# "Duplicated" vs "multiplicated" - for an element copied multiple times

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Let's say I have an Excel sheet and I need to make sure I have unique rows in the sheet.

There are rows, however, which are the same and present in the sheet 2 or more times.

Now, if there is **one** copy of another row, I'd say the row is "duplicated". But what is the correct form in the case when a row is copied **2+** times? Does "duplicated" still make sense? Or should I say the row is "multiplicated" (which sound a bit off, for some reason)?

Comment: Multiple duplicates are still duplicates, so *duplicated* is fine. So is the plain *copied*. You *might* be able to get away with saying that the row has *multiplied*, but that uses the term in the sense of biological reproduction (*multiplied like rabbits*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[replicate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/replicate)  (Oxford)

> 1 Make an exact copy of; reproduce.

This term is independent of number of copies.

Answer (score 0):

A good words for describing the same kind of information in the same format could be:

- Replicated
- Repeated
- Multiple entries